# socket file descriptors are the same among different processes

Tags: c++, bash, sockets

I have a simple server-client program. When I establish connections for all clients via a loop in the same c++ program, each client is assigned a different file descriptor for its connection to server. But when I establish connections in separate programs (e.g. using the following script), all clients get the same socket fd:

```
for i in {1..3}
do
  ./client &
done
```

The output in the first case (clients being invoked in a for-loop) is:

```
output on Server:
    For client 0 on sock 3
    For client 1 on sock 4
    For client 2 on sock 5
output on Client-version1: 
    Client connected to server on sock 4
    Client connected to server on sock 6
    Client connected to server on sock 7
```

and the output in the second case (being invoked in separate processes) is:

```
output on Server:
    For client 0 on sock 3
    For client 1 on sock 4
    For client 2 on sock 5
output on Client 1-version2: 
    Client connected to server on sock 3
output on Client 2-version2:    
    Client connected to server on sock 3
output on Client 3-version2:    
    Client connected to server on sock 3
```

Here's my code:

**client(version 1).cpp**

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd[3];
    std::string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    char temp_char;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        establish_tcp_connection(ip.c_str(), 45678, &sockfd[i]);
        printf("Client connected to server on sock %d", sockfd[i]);
    }

    // make sure that the socket is not closed before other clients start
    // so, just send a dummy char back and forth
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        sock_sync_data (sockfd, 1, "W", &temp_char);    

    return 0;
}
```

**client(version 2).cpp**

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd;
    std::string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    char temp_char;

    establish_tcp_connection(ip.c_str(), 45678, &sockfd);
    printf("Client connected to server on sock %d", sockfd);

    // make sure that the socket is not closed before other clients start
    // so, just send a dummy char back and forth
    sock_sync_data (sockfd, 1, "W", &temp_char);    

    return 0;
}
```

**Server.cpp**

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int CLIENTS_CNT = 3;
    int server_sockfd;
    char temp_char;
    int sockfd[CLIENTS_CNT];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, returned_addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(returned_addr);

    server_sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(45678);

    bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen (server_sockfd, CLIENTS_CNT);

    for (int c = 0; c < CLIENTS_CNT; c++){
        sockfd[c] = accept (server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &returned_addr, &len);
        printf("For client %d on sock %d", c, sockfd[c]);
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < CLIENTS_CNT; c++) {
        /* just send a dummy char back and forth */
        sock_sync_data (sockfd[c], 1, "W", &temp_char); 
    }

    close(server_sockfd);
}
```

And here's my **util** code:

```
int sock_connect (std::string servername, int port) {
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((char*)servername.c_str());
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) LESS_THAN_SIGN 0){ 
        printf("ERROR connecting");
        return -1;
    }
    return sockfd;
}

int establish_tcp_connection(std::string remote_ip, int remote_port, int *sockfd) {
    *sockfd = sock_connect (remote_ip, remote_port);
    if (*sockfd < 0) {
        printf("failed to establish TCP connection to server ");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the output from the client and server?

Comment: Why do you think the clients should get different FD numbers?

Comment: @immibis I changed the question a bit. Regarding the question, shouldn't they? Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought that each call to `socket` function should return a unique file descriptor.

Comment: I agree, They are the same. Why is this unexpected? Why do you care? What's the *real* problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File descriptor is usually an index in file descriptor table which is created by OS kernel per each process. So, their numbers a actually independent, and number 3 you get is actually first number after (0, 1, 2 - stdin, stdout and stderr accordingly).

However socket pseudo-files may have inode numbers which are global across system. They are harder to reach.

Comment: so when two separate processes write/read on sockets with the same socket number, they're actually writing/reading to/from different endpoints?

Comment: @narengi Not exactly. When you try to read from socket with fd = 3, you call `read(3, ...)`, OS checks third entry in fd table, finds that it is a socket and transfers your request to network stack with appropriate socket entity (which is stored in fd table). The magic that happens in network stack is a bit complex, but not of concern of common file handling layer.

Comment: @narengi, try to call `lsof -p <PID of client process>`. I hope, it would improve your understanding of what fd actually is.

Comment: This helped much. Thank you. So to conclude (and verify that my understanding is not wrong), OS maintains a table of open file descriptors, each of which is not necessarily unique among the fd space of other processes (e.g. multiple processes might have the entry fd=3 in their table), but the combination of <fd, PID> is unique. does it seem about right?

Answer (score 2):

File descriptors are specific to a process. There's nothing wrong with having the same number in two different processes refer to two different files. Indeed, FD 0 is always standard input, and standard input can be redirected for different processes.

In your second case, all three clients create different sockets, but they all have FD number 3 (within that process).

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal. A socket is just another file descriptor, so it's just a one-up... The OS's network stack handles all the endpoint information, etc, that you seem to believe should be part of the FD.